Teleport freely in Unreal-HandGameplay template
I am using this template from:
https://github.com/oculus-samples/Unreal-HandGameplay
I need to teleport freely anywhere around the scene instead of using the teleport pods provided.
How can I do this?

Use the AimingActor blueprint to do a line trace by channel downwards to detect floor and move the character to it’s position.
